# PHP URL Problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question in PHP.

I have a website thats hold news from mysql the (title, date, author, description) everything works fine, I have a page when which the user click on the title he go readmore.php?id=10 (for example)

Now my question is how to make to read the full story in one single page

for example index.php?id=10, I don't want to send in the readmore.php page, I want in one single page, how can I make this ?

Comment: Add whatever you put in `readmore.php` to `index.php`?

Comment: Yes right, when I click I can read but the other news stay in the top of my full story, can you understand?

Comment: someone with editing privilege pls. reword the question.

Comment: You got several proper answers, please mark one as such :)

Answer (score 2):

```
check there is **id** querystring .
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
     // show news which belongs to **id**
}
else
{
     // list all news
}
```

But **don't forgot** validating $_GET["id"] variable. For example, if **ids** only numeric, you can check use *is_numeric();* etc.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your current scripts but maybe you can modify the readmore.php page to only send the body of the page and then `require ("readmore.php");`  in your index.php where you need the full story, if the parameter (id) is the same. Then you can use something to show/hide the full body of the news in a div, in example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jquery plugin for that, for example [jQuery Expander Plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html)

Comment: Yes @mdaguerre this is a great tool, but I mean in PHP

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could send a get variable like: index.php?id=10&full=1. So, if full == 1 in index.php yo can show all the news, else cut the news with [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

url like so:

```
index.php <- normal news page
index.php?readstory=10 <- will display story with id 10
```

in index.php

```
if(isset($_GET['readstory'])) {
  $story_id = $_GET['readstory'];
  display_story($story_id);
}
else {
  display_news();
}
```

Comment: can you write the functions (display_story) and (display_news)

Comment: No, that's the php code you'll run to render your story or your normal index page :)